# OnItemSelectedListener in Dialog

Tags: android, android-spinner, onitemselectedlistener

I have a spinner in a dialog and I am trying to get the value from the selected item in spinner and pass it to a String variable. The method that I have found was spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener().

However, this method requires another method to be set up outside the dialog. Code attached below.

This is the code of the dialog

```
private void recordDialog() {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this);
    View subView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.record, null);

    //get current date
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    String pattern = "dd-MMM-yy";
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
    final String currentDate = dateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());

    //get category
    final Spinner spinner = subView.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.category, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    ...
    final AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

And the part outside the dialog

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    String selectedCategory = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
}
```

Is there anyway to complete everything within the dialog?

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. Appreciate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you could just implement the `onItemSelectedListener` inside your `recordDialog`function:

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
      public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
         // Do your stuff here    
      }

      public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
         // Do your stuff here  
      }
  });
}
```